# php class for seo

Tags: php, class

I recently use the great php class call : [Google Analytics PHP API](http://www.swis.nl/ga/). I manage to get it working to get a lot of info and stats for my 25+ website that have analytic

Now i like to get more data like

- The page rank the google placement
- (where i am on google #325 or #520)
- Google Page Rank
- Google Indexed Pages
- Traffic Rank
- Inbound Links
- DMOZ Directory
- Yahoo! Directory

get a summary (my way) much more like http://websitegrader.com

do you know a php class to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get all from alexa api (Alexa Web Services)

http://aws.amazon.com/awis/

but not free

$0.00015 per request ($0.15 for 1,000 requests)

i thought in the past to build a website to arrange an Arab sites
but arrived at the checkpoint

somme website use awis
www.statbrain.com
www.websiteoutlook.com
www.websitevaluecalculator.com

Answer (score 2):

I guarantee you're not going to find one "class" that does all that for you.

Manually checking your site's rank on Alexa is probably going to be your best source of information on top of what Google Analytics is already giving you.

Google Analytics does NOT require any sort of API.

**The site you linked to asks for your Google username/password. I'm flagging this question. I encourage others to do the same.**

Comment: Google username/password ust because GOOGLE ask that for getting you to the information stat... i have the code and nothing wrong is done here... i not even my php class... i use it and modify it from the author, i used it locally ! work fine !

Comment: Nothing you said supports the issue of whether Stack Overflow users should be subjected to a link that asks for their personal credentials. That's just plain phishing.